# Spring Boot on Azure Docker container for Linux fails to authenticate to Azure SQL Server on AAD Identity: KrbException

Tags: java, azure, jdbc, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-server

I believe I included everything in my title.

I have a Spring Boot application built with Gradle and jib as a Docker Linux container.

```
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc_auth:9.4.0.x64'
```

The application is now being deployed to **Azure Web App for Containers**, where I had set the web app's AAD identity via the **Identity** tab, and also assigned a **Contributor** role in the target SQL Server.

I was confident that everything was set. The app ships with [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org), so it self-creates the tables in the default schema.

I had set the environment variable below in Azure configuration tab

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://????.database.windows.net:1433;database=?????;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated
```

And I thought it was everything required.

Instead, the exception is (exactly as Docker locally)

```
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891324272Z Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891327972Z  at java.security.jgss/javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosPrincipal.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[java.security.jgss:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891331972Z  at java.security.jgss/javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosPrincipal.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[java.security.jgss:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891335972Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthTokenIntegrated(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:106) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891339872Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:4849) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891343672Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:4724) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891348072Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:4680) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891352072Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onFedAuthInfo(tdsparser.java:289) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891355872Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:125) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891359673Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891363573Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5560) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891367373Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4289) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891371173Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:88) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891375073Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4227) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891378773Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7417) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891382573Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3488) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891386373Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2978) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891393373Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2628) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891397373Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2471) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891401273Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1470) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891405173Z  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:915) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891408973Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891412773Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891417173Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891421173Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891424973Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891428873Z  ... 32 common frames omitted
2021-12-23T15:51:35.891432573Z
```

Locally, it was pretty obvious. I have absolutely no KRB configuration.

But I thought Azure automagically configures the container when I navigate the Identity tab on the portal (where my app's identity is, namely, `395f00ce-c4ed-4be5-ac35-7767f4799555`)

Question: is there anything else that I can/must do in order to configure passwordless backend-to-backend authentication for a web app to Azure SQL Server?

I have read a few [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-containers-ad-auth-adutil-tutorial?view=sql-server-ver15) that include a number of configuration steps at *machine* level, but we are talking about a container that is deployed and managed by Azure. I don't know if those apply. The Docker image is a Spring Boot-compatible image built by Jib, so I don't have a Dockerfile

Comment: have you logged in to Azure from the container / web app using az login --identity

Comment: No. I haven't run anything *from* the container. It's just a plain Docker/Spring Boot image based on Java 11. I don't think the container has the `az` command available in `$PATH`. I don't know the effects of `az login` **but** I have assigned an identity to the web app via Azure Portal web interface. I don't know if it has the same effect of the above command, specified in the question. That GUID is `Collaborator` in the SQL database

Answer (score 0):

> Question: is there anything else that I can/must do in order to
> configure passwordless backend-to-backend authentication for a web app
> to Azure SQL Server?

As you are using System Assigned Managed Identity for your web app and provided the Contributor role to the SQL server, you need to login to the Azure from your spring boot application

You can configure your spring boot application to use System Assigned Managed Identity in your application code

Then you would be able to access Azure SQL server from your web app without any password

Comment: `You can configure your spring boot application to use System Assigned Managed Identity in your application code` => could you kindly provide some guidance on this task? I only found a Microsoft tutorial about retrieving Managed Identity tokens via http (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#get-a-token-using-java) but I don't know yet how to integrate that into Spring Boot